# Make flex items wrap in nested flex containers before containers themselves wrap in main container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have a flexbox container containing multiple containers, how do I make the containers' contained items wrap before the containers themselves?

For example ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOeRRz)):

HTML

```
<div>
    <row>
        <column id="first">
            <widget width=1 height=8></widget>
            <widget width=1 height=8></widget>
        </column>
        <row id="second">
            <widget></widget>
            <widget></widget>
            <widget></widget>
        </row>
    </row>
</div>
```

CSS

```
column, row, widget {
  background: RGBA(0,0,0,.2);
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: top;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

widget {
  min-height: 100px;
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: calc(25% - 3em);
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  display: block;
}

widget[width=1] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 150px;
}

widget[width=4] {
  flex-grow: 4;
  min-width: 600px;
}

widget[width=8] {
  flex-grow: 8;
  min-width: 1200px;
}

widget[height=1] {
  min-height: 150px;
}

widget[height=4] {
  min-height: 600px;
}

widget[height=8] {
  min-height: 1200px;
}

widget {
  background: RGBA(200,0,20,.5);
}
```

I want the items in `#second` to wrap before `#second` itself wraps below `#first`. In other words, I always want to try wrapping the innermost items before trying to wrap the outermost ones, which seems to be the opposite of what happens by default. Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT:** There were requests for visual clarification.

2 containers with several items each:
[image: full width]

Desired behavior, slightly smaller. Innermost items wrap before their containers.

[image: partially wrapped]

Desired behavior, smaller still.

[image: inner items fully wrapped]

Desired behavior, smallest. After the innermost items can't wrap any more, the containers finally wrap.

[image: containers wrapped]

What actually happens: the containers wrap before their contents.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the desired behavior. Can you add an image or something?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there are any flex properties that make this process simple and easy. However, the flexbox specification does allow for [absolutely-positioned flex children](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#abspos-items). So with a combination of media queries and absolute positioning, the flex items within the container can be made to wrap before the container itself wraps.

Try this:

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS** (add media queries and absolute positioning)

```
#second { position: relative; } 
/* establishes nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { 
    #second widget:nth-child(3) { 
        position: absolute; 
        left: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        width: 90%; }
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {  
    #second { height: 375px; }
    #second widget:nth-child(2) { 
        position: absolute; 
        left: 0; 
        bottom: 127px; 
        width: 75%; }
    #second widget:nth-child(3) { 
        position: absolute; 
        left: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        width: 75%; }   
    }

/* final media query removes absolute positioning and restores flex properties */       
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
    column, row, widget { flex-wrap: wrap; }
    #second widget {
        position: static;
        width: calc(25% - 3em);
        min-width: 300px;
    }
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjNedd)

Note that although this code does what the question asks – it wraps flex items in their container before the container itself wraps – it's only meant to convey the basic concept of the solution. Issues like margin and width for flex items, which I considered beyond the scope of this question, may still need to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way to do this without knowing the widths of the items (widgets) ahead-of-time?

Comment: The widths I used are based on the widths in your code. However, if you remove widths, the boxes will be only as wide as needed to wrap the content. Like I mentioned at the end of the answer, this solution is one way to achieve what you want but -- not knowing anything about your content -- you may need to make adjustments (possibly using `min-width`, `max-width` and `overflow` properties) to make this work smoothly.

Comment: But every time I added/subtracted items from the page, I'd have to alter the CSS too, right? This basically just hardcodes the preferred wrapping behavior, it's not general?

Comment: Do the widgets need to be in a container? If you remove `#second` and just have the widgets as child items of `row`, all this code could be scrapped. Otherwise, yes to your two questions, since there is no CSS property the forces flex items to wrap before their container, the workaround code can get a bit messy. You may want to consider Javascript for an alternative.