# Nested row flexbox with wrapping on multiple levels

Tags: css, flexbox

I am making responsive design where elements wrap to next line in certain way when there is not enough space, however I cannot make it working.

Requirements:

1. There are 3 elements (actually more, but this is minimal example), all with automatic size depending on their content: one aligned on the left, two - on the right.
2. They are placed inside container which always spans at least 100% width of parent.
3. If there is not enough space for elements to be all on one line, then right element should begin to wrap to next line, while still all being to the right of left element.
4. If there is still not enough space, only then right elements go under left one.
5. If there is still not enough space, then container expands in size.

Here are examples how it should work (red lines represent viewport borders):

[image: requirements examples]

Here is code I come up with so far, but it starts wrapping immediately on outer level, not on innermost as I need:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: min-content;
  background-color: rgb(224, 191, 146); /* for visibility */
}
#child-left {
  background-color: rgb(92, 189, 40); /* for visibility */
  /* imitate content for demo, in actual code size is not set */
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50px;
}
#child-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: rgb(111, 72, 20); /* for visibility */
}
#grandchild-right-1 {
  background-color: rgb(40, 102, 189); /* for visibility */
  /* imitate content for demo, in actual code size is not set */
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
#grandchild-right-2 {
  background-color: rgb(189, 40, 112); /* for visibility */
  /* imitate content for demo, in actual code size is not set */
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child-left">1</div>
  <div id="child-right">
    <div id="grandchild-right-1">2</div>
    <div id="grandchild-right-2">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can fix this by adding `flex: 1` to the `child-right` class.

Comment: @PhobosFerro At first glance seems working, thanks. I will test it a bit more. Could you post it as an answer then?

Comment: Actually this question looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661535/make-flex-items-wrap-in-nested-flex-containers-before-containers-themselves-wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `flex: 1`.

Remember that `flex` is a shorthand property for `flex: 1 1 0` or `flex-grow: 1`, `flex-shrink: 1` and `flex-basis: 0`.
As a result, this makes the elements take any empty space in the container, hopping to the next line if theres no space left.

https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/

Comment: It needs as well `justify-content: flex-end;` on `#child-right`, so elements are on the right side. Other than that, works well, thanks!

Comment: Tried that as well, but didnt know if you wanted them to stay on the right hand side. Glad it helped!

Comment: I needed them initially be on the right side (when there is plenty space). Adding `flex-end` has side effect of aligning them on the right even when they are wrapped, but that in my case is not a big deal.

Comment: You would have to use javascript to change that. Something like if `#child-right` and `#container` have the same width change the style of `#child-right`